# How much will I earn by running Bitcoin-Qt?

Tags: transaction-fees, full-node

I'm running `Bitcoin-Qt` on a dedicated server with a good connection (although, only a modest cpu). What is the frequency with which I will earn bitcoins?

Answer (score 6):

Transaction fees are earned only by miners.  Running Bitcoin-QT, you will *relay* transactions and blocks for other people, but this does not earn you any fee.